# Optimal (in terms of remaining vector lengths) 2-dimensional projection plane of $n$ $d$-dimensional unit vectors

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, projection

I have a finite number of $n$ unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$. I would like to find a two-dimensional projection plane such that each vector has a length larger than 0 in the projection. Moreover, I would like to maximize the minimal vector length in the projection.

Are there any well-known results about the existence of such a plane?

Answer (score 1):

Such planes exist. Each plane in $\Bbb R^4$ has a unique normal plane passing through the origin. points in the normal plane project to $0$, while all other points do not project to $0$.

So pick any plane that does not contain any of your unit vectors, which must exist as there are only finitely many vectors to avoid and uncountably many planes. Then take the normal plane to the one you picked. The projections of all your vectors onto that plane will have the desired property.

Comment: Why does such a plane maximize the minimal vector length?

Comment: I never said it did. I answered your existence question. I fully admit I haven't touched the optimization question. I'm not an expert in optimization.